# vim c++ syntax contained region

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I define four key words and two regions in vim scripts

```
syn keyword KeywordA A nextgroup=rangeA skipwhite skipnl skipempty
syn keyword KeywordB B contained containedin=rangeA nextgroup=rangeB skipwhite skipnl skipempty
syn keyword KeywordC C contained containedin=rangeA
syn keyword KeywordD D contained containedin=rangeB

syn region rangeA start=+{+ end=+}+ contained transparent
syn region rangeB start=+{+ end=+}+ contained transparent

hi KeywordA ctermfg=blue
hi KeywordB ctermfg=green
hi KeywordC ctermfg=cyan
hi KeywordD ctermfg=red
```

The keywords A and B has two corresponding regions.

**When the file is saved as .cpp or .c**

The highlighting result is like this:

[image: highlighting]

Actually, the D is in rangeB,
but D is not highlighted.

**However, if I change the file extension to .t**

the result is what I expect:

[image]

Is there any solution that I can highlight C and D in rangeB in a cpp file?
(Since C in rangeB is also in rangeA)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your syntax interferes with the built-in C/C++ syntax script. Adding such large modifications to an existing syntax is very difficult, and may even require modifications to the original syntax. If possible, develop your syntax independently.

Comment: @IngoKarkat That may be a solution. Is there any way to disable the default syntax and use mine instead?

Comment: You can switch with `:setlocal syntax=yourcppdialect`; or (a bit cleaner) define a completely new filetype and just reuse the parts (e.g. ftplugins) from C++ via `:runtime`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat A strange thing I found is that as long as the file has .cpp file extension, I will fail to highlight correctly, no matter what I set, including `:setlocal syntax=xxx` and `:set filetype=xx`. But when I change the file extension, nothing goes wrong.

Comment: It probably needs a `:syntax clear`; that's what all syntax scripts start with.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I've tried it but the problem still exists. I even try to remove the c.vim and cpp.vim in both `ftplugin` and `syntax`, but neither does it work.